# Add fingerprint to PDF in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, fingerprinting

I need to find an javascript library that can add a fingerprint to an PDF.
The fingerprint is something similar to the output of the function: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/58c3ea08202becf007c304512c44726719acb508/src/core/core.js#L513

Does anybody know such library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware the word "Fingerprint" has different meaning due to context. In Mozilla it means the ID which is the same for two copies of a PDF.

A PDF fingerprint is mandatory / required when a PDF is encrypted so any library that encrypts PDF with a password will need to include the ability to add a fingerprint.

see extracts from PDF standard

"A PDF document can be encrypted (PDF 1.1) to protect its contents from unauthorized access. Encryption
applies to all strings and streams in the document's PDF file, with the following exceptions:
•
The values for the ID entry in the trailer"

"File identifiers shall be defined by the optional ID entry in a PDF file’s trailer dictionary (see 7.5.5, “File Trailer”).
The ID entry is optional but should be used. The value of this entry shall be an array of two byte strings. The
first byte string shall be a permanent identifier based on the contents of the file at the time it was originally
created and shall not change when the file is incrementally updated. The second byte string shall be a
changing identifier based on the file’s contents at the time it was last updated. When a file is first written, both
identifiers shall be set to the same value. If both identifiers match when a file reference is resolved, it is very
likely that the correct and unchanged file has been found. If only the first identifier matches, a different version
of the correct file has been found."

"NOTE
The calculation of the file identifier need not be reproducible; all that matters is that the identifier is likely to be
unique. For example, two implementations of the preceding algorithm might use different formats for the
current time, causing them to produce different file identifiers for the same file created at the same time, but the
uniqueness of the identifier is not affected."

So you can use any 32byte string you like as long as its hex and unique

In summary two identical twins of a PDF must have different fingerprints if born one second after each other. But two files that are totally different dont need to have fingerprints OR their fingerprint can be identical when produced or modified at different times and locations, like much of PDF handling it is not standard except when printed.